# AlarmManager not work for date specific

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

AlarmManager execute in current date, but i need in 10h.

My code for schedule in AlarmManager

```
public class RecieverAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    intent = new Intent(context, BootReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,25202,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
        }
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

With the Calendar class i get the correct long value, but AlarmManager runs on time and not on the schedule sent by the Calendar class.

Comment: If you want it to fire 10 hours from now, then you want to use `calendar.add()`, not `calendar.set()`. Also, the `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())` call is unnecessary, as the instance returned from `getInstance()` will already be set to the current date/time. And, there's a `getTimeInMillis()` method you can use instead of `calendar.getTime().getTime()`.